# Buttons on header are not clicked when canvas is loaded

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

When Canvas is loaded, the buttons on the header are not clicked.

I searched on Stackoverflow but I couldn't figure it out. I tried giving the canvas position: absolute and z-index but it didn't resolve.

I tried what everyone said as I saw it on Stackoverflow but still not solved. Could it be a bug in the JavaScript code? Or is there a different error? I leave the codes below.

JavaScript code:

https://pastebin.pl/view/9b4a9399

HTML code:

```
<canvas id="gradient-canvas">
</canvas>
```

I also use Stripe gradient. I also got it from: https://codepen.io/smitpatelx/pen/GRZayyO

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!, Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: And judging from the size of your pastebin, the important word here is MINIMAL